# pass server response to call back function in jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

So basically, I have a small plugin like below, what it does is submit the form with jquery method post.

```
(function($){
 $.fn.ajaxSubmit = function(options){
  var defaults = {
   url:'',
   success:function(){},
   error:function(){}
  },
  o = $.extend({},defaults, options);
  return this.each(function(){
   var $this=$(this);
   $this.submit(function(e){
    $.post(o.url,$this.serialize() ,
    function(response){
     if(response.status == 'success'){
      o.success.call(this);
     }
     else if(response.status == 'error'){
      o.error.call(this);
     }
    },'json');
    return false;
   });
  });
 }
})(jQuery);
```

This is how its called

```
$('#form').ajaxSubmit({
  url:'www.myownwebsite.com/play/processform',
  success:function(response){alert(response.status)},
  error:function(response){alert(response.status);}
 });
```

The problem is, when the script is executed, I get the error "response is undefined". Clearly I know whats wrong, but how can I do it properly?

Comment: Please... my eyes... use whitespace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried `o.success.call(this,response);`